# Force WAMP to use IP address rather than localhost

Tags: wamp, mediawiki

I've just installed WAMP and MediaWiki on a different box (a local machine on my network) however I want to view MediaWiki through my local machine and then add articles, etc. I installed MediaWiki on the remote box and configured it, I then returned to my local machine, typed in the IP address of the MediaWiki on the remote box (hsomething like `http://100.100.100.100/wiki/index.php/Main_Page`) and noticed that when changing preferences and saving the URL uses localhost and not the IP address (basically after I have posted via a Form Submit). Is this a setting I can change in WAMP or is it a setting I'll have to change in MediaWiki?

You may have noticed I'm a bit of newbi to this kind of thing.

Many thanks

Comment: sounds like it's probably in this 'mediawiki' somewhere. I'd look for an ini or cfg file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panic over, in the LocalSettings file for mediaWiki you can set the following $wgServer to your IP address.

Answer (score 3):

There is a configuration file named localsettings.php in wamp/www/wiki

Open it with notepad and carefully remove the following:

```
$wgServer           = "http://192.168.0.1"
```

(where 192.168.0.1 is the host name you used)

Stop and start WAMP and it should work